# Subtracting two dataframes by selecting only specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` like this:

```
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      1     15      1      262
1      1     10      2      263
2      1      5      0      315
3      1      7      3      316

   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      2     23      3      262
1      2     13      5      263
2      2     11      3      315
3      2     19      5      316
```

What I want to do is perform a subtraction like `df3 = df2 - df1`. However I would like to subtract only the `fouls` and `goals` columns and keep the `round` and `team_id` columns unchanged.

If I perform `df3 = df2 - df1` I get:

```
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      1      8      2        0
1      1      3      3        0
2      1      6      3        0
3      1     12      2        0
```

What can I do in order to get the following:

```
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      2      8      2      262
1      2      3      3      263
2      2      6      3      315
3      2     12      2      316
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify columns for subtract in list:

```
cols = ['fouls','goals']
df2[cols] = df2[cols]- df1[cols]
print (df2)
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      2      8      2      262
1      2      3      3      263
2      2      6      3      315
3      2     12      2      316
```

Or specify columns for exclude columns names with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for columns for subtract:

```
exclude = ['round','team_id']
cols = df1.columns.difference(exclude)
df2[cols] = df2[cols]- df1[cols]
print (df2)
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      2      8      2      262
1      2      3      3      263
2      2      6      3      315
3      2     12      2      316
```

For new DataFrame use:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
cols = df1.columns.difference(['round','team_id'])
df3[cols] = df2[cols]- df1[cols]
print (df3)
   round  fouls  goals  team_id
0      2      8      2      262
1      2      3      3      263
2      2      6      3      315
3      2     12      2      316
```

Comment: Question, can you generatre a new dataframe out of the difference? For instance, is the following (creating df3) a valid syntax? `df3[cols] = df2[cols] - df1[cols]`

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky - I think close is `df3 = df2[cols] - df1[cols]`, solution `df3[cols] = df2[cols] - df1[cols]` is problem, because `df3` not exist

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky You can do `df3 = df2` before you do the subtraction and then perform `df3[cols] = df2[cols] - df1[cols]`

Comment: Ah, it's true! Thanks for your answer guys! @jezrael you coding beast!